# Asp.Net MVC: requests with too long URLs and error handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, error-handling

By checking my elmah log, I see I keep receiving "too long url" requests. The error is:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

Here is the kind of requests I receive:

> /index.php/blog/post/the_ten_deceptions_of_the_datetimepicker/+[PLM=0]+GET+http:/www.visualhint.com/index.php/blog/post/the_ten_deceptions_of_the_datetimepicker/+[0,23778,23037]+->+[N]+POST+http:/www.visualhint.com/index.php/blog/post/the_ten_deceptions_of_the_datetimepicker/+[0,0,2007]

(don't be surprised by the php thing... before being an asp.net mvc site, my site was in php and now I need to redirect this kind of old URLs to my new url format, which works well when the url stops at /index.php/blog/post/the_ten_deceptions_of_the_datetimepicker)

1. What could generate these requests? Does it sound malicious?
2. I have custom errors setup, so I though such a request would be redirected to my custom error page, but it's not. Instead, people get the typical yellow screen (firebug mentions this is a 400 Bad Request). If you look at the above stack trace, it is very short and the exception seems to be caught very early (Application_BeginRequest is not even called). Is it possible to show my custom error page or can I at least redirect to my homepage when such an exception occurs?

I tried adding a line for error 400 in my web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
    <error statusCode="400" redirect="/" />
</customErrors>
```

This redirects to the homepage right, but it adds the complete url in an aspxerrorpath query string value.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The advice here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185739/asp-net-mvc-url-routing-maximum-path-url-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google search helped me find that some other people get this kind of request. Someone answered with:

> I am pretty sure it is an automated way of submitting spam. There must
>   be an error in the configuration because it should not leave such a
>   juicy trail in the referrer field!
>
> First it tells some script to get an URL, then it instructs to post to
>   an URL (it is easy to block spam that POSTs directly without getting
>   first).
>
> The numbers could be relating to what spam message(s) to post (think
>   of it as indexes in a spam DB).

So, since there are good chances that these requests are not from humans following normal links, I ended up with the following solution. This avoids polluting my elmah log and this serves a blank page to the caller with a 404 code:

```
public void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    HttpException hExc = e.Exception.GetBaseException() as HttpException;
    if (hExc != null)
    {
        if (hExc.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x80004005))
        {
            e.Dismiss();
            return;
        }
    }

    // Here I do some stuff if the error has to be logged.
}

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
    HttpException hExc = exc as HttpException;
    if (hExc != null)
    {
        if (hExc.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x80004005))
        {
            Uri uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;

            Response.Clear();
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            Response.End();

            Server.ClearError();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of returning a 404 code, I would have preferred to not send a response (the caller would have a timeout) but is it possible with asp.net? No idea...