# MVC router throws invalid character in the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the below route in MVC3 application

```
context.MapRoute("RoutName", "GetReport/{Id1}/{Id2}/{requestId}/{customerId}/
{CustomerVersion}/{Code}", new {controller= "ControllerName",action = "GetReport" });
```

This route works fine for below URL in the local environment

```
http://localhost/ControllerName/GetReport/104334/120531211240541002/120531211240551002
/120531211237331002/1/Code
```

But in the server i am getting "Access Blocked due to invalid characters in URL". Is there restriction on the length of the URL in MVC?

Any input would be great.

Comment: Does this question help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185739/asp-net-mvc-url-routing-maximum-path-url-length ?

Comment: I took a look the link and the URL length seems to be less than 150 characters. I am not sure what the issue in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented your code in an empty MVC3 project but I'm not able to trigger your error, here the code just works fine.

ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "GetReport", "Home", new { Id1 = 104334, Id2 = 120531211240541002, requestId = 120531211240551002, customerId = 120531211237331002, CustomerVersion = 1, Code = "Code" }, null)
```

ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult GetReport(string Id1, string Id2, string requestId, string customerId, string CustomerVersion, string Code)
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

What's different in your version?

Comment: Looks like the problem in the sever is due to some other component and now it seems to work correctly. Thanx for taking a dig at it.