# Bad Request - Invalid URL web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am working on a web-api and I have set the web config file to accept  6144 as the max length of the url as below

```xml
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="6144" 
                 relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"
                 targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

When I call the api with 299 characters everything works fine, but with more than 299 characters it serves up a Bad Request - Invalid URL

sample url:

`http://localhost:56835/api/multibuys/10270001C1001034900|10358419P4001027620|10781772P4805004950|10781772P4805004950|10781772P4805004950|10781772P4805004950|10781772P4805004950|10781772P4805004950|10781772P4805004950|10781772P4805004950|10781772P4805004950|10781772P4805004950|10781772P4805004950|`

Comment: Try using IIS express instead of Cassini.

Comment: maybe something in this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185739/asp-net-mvc-url-routing-maximum-path-url-length

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same issue when self hosting web-api. I would guess the limit you are hitting is the `UrlSegmentMaxLength` default from Http.sys.

To fix this you need to add a *new* registry DWORD under

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters

[image]

called `UrlSegmentMaxLength` and give this the value you desire:

> UrlSegmentMaxLength    260 0 - 32,766 chars    Maximum number of characters in a URL path segment (the area between the slashes in the URL). If zero, it is the length that is bounded by the maximum value of a ULONG.

To add via the command line use (elevated prompt)

```
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters /v UrlSegmentMaxLength /t REG_DWORD /d 32766 /f
```

References:
https://serverfault.com/questions/66410/iis-6-on-x64-and-long-urls
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129