# MVC kendo Grid - Read method fails when parameter is too long

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

I am using the MVC Kendo Grid
This is my Read method:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
                       .Name("Grid")
                       .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                        }
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
 .Ajax()
 .Read(read => read.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { ids = 
     Model.SelectedIds }))
      )
  )
```

Model.SelectedIds is a comma separated string of ids, which I split in the controller and fetch records for the Ids.
This works fine if Model.SelectedIds is a small string
However, when it is a huge string with many ids (3000 for example), then the Action is never called.

Wherever I am sending Json data, I have already set the Json limit to max in the web.config file. Here, I don't think it should affect, since this is not a Json request, correct?

Please help me fix this.

The Action is as below:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(DataSourceRequest request, string ids){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you need to check the [max request length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded) and if your using url then check the [max url length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185739/asp-net-mvc-url-routing-maximum-path-url-length). Also, there is a config element that can control the json length.

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="99999999" />                                          
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by sending the data as an object instead of a param

```
.Read(read => read.Action("MyAction", "MyController").Data
("postData"))
```

JavaScript code

```
function postData() {
    return { ids: $("#SelectedIds").val() };
}
```

Comment: This could be that your app was cutting, ignoring a url over a certain threshold. Does it work Now?

Comment: Yes, it does now. Thanks!