# MVC: How to serialize a knockout object into a JSON property through AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I'm trying to serialize a knockout object and pass it into a JSON property called **multipleCharge**.

This is the ajax code to send data though Get method to a mvc controller

```
        $.ajax({
            url: _url,
            type: 'GET',
            //data: { multipleCharge: ko.mapping.toJS(_vm)},
            data: { multipleCharge : { AccountId : 2 } },
            dataType: 'json'});
```

And this is the method

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSalesInvoiceMultipleCharge
    ([FromUri]MultipleChargeDto multipleCharge)
{
    ...
}
```

Please, note that the ajax method has a comment line. Using the hardcoded line, it works, multipleCharge object is not null, but if I uncomment the another line, it's a bad request in my browser.

Look at this.

[image]

[image]

Any idea about what's happening. Using the Chrome console, it looks ok; so I can't identify the error.

Comment: May be URL is very long.

Comment: so, does URLs have limit lenght?

Answer (score 0):

It is may be IIS problems with very long URL.
See this [Issue with URL length in IIS7 (Windows Server 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762387/issue-with-url-length-in-iis7-windows-server-2008) question and related answers.
Also see this http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering documentation.
You could try to solve this problem by editing web.config. But also you could use POST method instead of GET and send your data in request body.